# Gear step sizes between Shimano Nexus 8 and Alfine 8 compatible

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, nexus

I recently replaced my broken nexus 8 with a new alfine 8.

i thought that they are compatible in regards to the shifter and the step sizes between the gears.

but i notice now on the alfine that i dont hit all gears precisely. there is sometimes a slipping on the very high gears and very low gears.

so are step sizes on nexus and alfine gears compatible or not?

Comment: Step sizes and hitting the gear are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Alfine 8 and Nexus 8 can use the same shifters. I'm guessing you need to adjust the shifter by turning the barrel adjuster on the shifter (there are marks on the hub which need to be lined up in order for it to shift properly -- check the setup instructions for the hub/shifter).